# Compiling and initializing external JS library in Laravel mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix

I am using Laravel mix to compile all my assets, but I'm having trouble initializing an external library.

I have used `npm install aos --save` to get the dependency, and within my `app.js` I am calling it like this:

```
require('aos/dist/aos');
AOS.init();
```

My mix file:

```
mix
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/index.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/sass/index.scss', 'public/css');
```

Now inside a view I am including the file in `head`:

```
<script defer src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

But I keep getting in my view that

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: AOS is not defined
```

How can I resolve it? If it is being referenced within same file and after the library requiring, why is it not working?

Comment: Try with `import AOS from 'aos'; AOS.init()` or `var AOS = require('aos');
AOS.init();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off the [README](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos#using-package-managers) on Github you can do:

```
import AOS from 'aos';

AOS.init();
```

---

If you're ever unsure about how to use a `npm` package it's always worth looking at the following (if they exist):

- Description on www.npmjs.com - Google `npm [package name]` or use the search on npmjs.com
- The repo README - The link for this is usually on the righthand side of the npmjs.com page
- Official Documentation site - If there is one, it will usually be found in one of the above.